# Changing the URL messed up my clients drupal site!

Tags: uri

I have been working on my clients site without a URL so to log in to the server we've been using the "ip address/~henryl"  The client told me to make the site live by transferring over his domain name - nooo problem!  Wait - YIKES! PROBLEM!!  Part of the old URL stayed when I transferred the domain.
I changed the $Base URL in the settings.php, I've commented out sections of the .htaccess - but now I can't even LOG IN to the site to fix the other issues I'm finding.  When I log in, it just drops me back onto the same homepage.  if I change the URL to include the "~henryl/" after the new domain name it does work to show me some back end areas.  I don't know what I've done!!  I ran a search on all my back end files and I can't find "~henryl" in any of the back code - so it has to be in the database somewhere - so obviously there's an option in drupal that I've changed and forgot about... dang!!  Can anyone help??  I really have to fix the issues with my clients site.
The site is www.hayfield.ca and for some reason I have 2 homepages www.hayfield.ca/~henryl

I'd appreciate ANY help!!!

**Additional**
if I go to: "http://www.hayfield.ca/~henryl/admin/dashboard" it says that the page doesn't exist 
if I go to: "www.hayfield.ca/admin/dashboard" it says that I am not authorized to see the page - even though I'm logged in...

Comment: i know this could be a long shot, but, the mod-rewrite is enabled on the new domain?

Comment: Well you got me thinking so I went and looked - seemed to be working fine, but something wasn't right so I tried commenting out the "RewriteEngine on" in the .htaccess  - uploaded it and it didn't work, then I uncommented the same line and uploaded it again - and low and behold now it's working.... perfectly... I'm at a loss as to what was actually wrong, but I'm soooo relieved that its working now!  Thanks for the hint - it put me on the right path!!

Comment: Sounds like caching issues.

Comment: @everaftergraphics If you found the answer to your own question, add it as an answer, not a comment.  On *Drupal Answers*, it is OK to answer your own question-- and even encouraged!

Comment: @PatrickKenny That comment doesn't sound like an answer. It just says that .htaccess has been edited to comment out a directive, then edited to add back that directive.

Comment: @beth - I'd cleared the cache and ran cron multiple times with no different result  :-(  -- unless there was a bug and it wasn't ACTUALLY clearing the cache??

Comment: @PatrickKenny -- I agree with Kiamlaluno, I commented because it really wasn't an answer to what the actual problem was.  I'd love to know what the actual problem was so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: Did you clear cache from the GUI or from Drush? If you cleared it from Drush, did it say it successfully cleared? Did it say "all cache was cleared" or "drush cache was cleared"? The latter indicates incomplete cache clear. You can also do it by looking at the database and truncating tables that start with "cache_".

Comment: To clear the cache - the only way it would let me was to use the admin Home menu - but after it re-loaded it took me to the page that said I was not authorized to see that page so I never actually new if clearing the cache was completed properly. Good to know that there's a back way to clear the cache in the database!!!! Thanks!!!